# Latest version of spacy-lefff incompatible with latest version of spacy

Tags: spacy

Installation of spacy-lefff v. 0.3.3 makes it impossible to run a Python program with module Spacy (v. 2.1.1)

The root problem seems to be the modules thinc and cymem. I tried to unstalled thinc and cymem but i don't know which version of thinc and cymem to reinstall afterwords.

There is no indication of the problem at https://github.com/sammous/spacy-lefff

There is an indication that "spacy-lefff requires spacy <= v2.0.12".

I tried to downgrade to spacy v. 2.0.12 but my code is not working because of modules thinc and cymem.

Operating System : Win 10
Python version : 3.7-2
Spacy version used : 2.1.1
Lefff version used : 0.3.3.

Thanks